# React useState return undefined with async await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, setstate

This code get a `token` and updates a local state created with `useState`. The problem is that at first token is `undefined` and when this happens, the app will crash because my code expects `token` to be defined later on. So my question is, why doesn't the setter correctly update the value? Specifically how to make things work normally with `async` functions? Initially `token` is `undefined` but it is defined on the second render.

```
export const Example = () => {
  async function fetchToken() {
    const res = await fetch("https://func-get-token.net/token");
    const result = await res.json();
    return { authToken: token };
  }

  const [token, setToken] = useState();

  async function asyncCall() {
    const tokenobj = await fetchToken();
    setToken(tokenobj);
  }

  const showToken = () => {
    asyncCall();
    console.log(token);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={showToken}>Test token value</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where in this code are you ever using or even observing this value?  Can you provide a [mcve] and indicate what actual problem you are observing?  The initial value of `token` is, by design, `undefined`.  You can specify an initial value in the call to `useState` if you like.  But if you have some other code not shown here which in any way *assumes* that `token` will never be `undefined` then that assumption is mistaken.

Comment: Updated the code to reflect what happening , and as I said the first call return  undefined

Comment: You aren't making a call before the button's clicked so of course the state will be undefined

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when `asyncCall()` is called, it doesn't wait for a response before running `console.log(token)`. If you convert the `showToken` function to an async function and then `await asyncCall()`, it will wait for the `fetch` call to finish before running the next line:

```js
const Example = () => {
  async function fetchToken() {
    const res = await fetch("https://func-get-token.net/token");
    const result = await res.json();
    return { authToken: token };
  }

  const [token, setToken] = useState();

  async function asyncCall() {
    const tokenobj = await fetchToken();
    setToken(tokenobj);
  }

  const showToken = async () => {
    await asyncCall();
    console.log(token);
  };

  return (
        <button onClick={showToken}>Test token value: {token}</button>
  );
};
```

Another issue is that in you never get the token from the `result`. I believe in `return {authToken: token}` the variable `token` should be `result` in this case.

Then you could even simplify this and move all the code into a single function `showToken`:

```js
const Example = () => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState();
  async function showToken() {
    const res = await fetch("https://func-get-token.net/token");
    const result = await res.json();
    setToken({ authToken: result });
    console.log(token);
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={showToken}>Test token value: {token}</button>
  );
};
```

In this case, the abstractions of having multiple functions I think makes the whole sync/async thing a little more confusing.

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the fact that enqueued React state updates won't be visible until the callstack completes and React processes all the enqueued updates and rerenders the component. In other words, the code in your answer still has basically the exact same problem as the OP's code. You can't just simply `await` the state update, state will be whatever it was when the callstack was started and never anything different.